# Análogo en español para "dinner party"

Tags: traducción

¿Existe alguna palabra, frase o expresión análoga en español, para la expresión inglesa, "**dinner party**"?

He buscado en la web, pero no he encontrado algo que me convenza.

Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La más cercana en mi opinión, a la expresión "**dinner party**",  es la locución "**Cena de amigos**", pues la frase va más allá de su típico formalismo, ya que lleva implícito el carácter festivo sobrentendido al tratarse de una reunión entre amigos que sirve de distracción, desahogo y ese sentimiento compartido de pasarlo bien. Normalmente es una frase que se utiliza y que sirve de excusa para juntarse y divertirse y menos para referirse al carácter formal de una velada. Al igual que se utilizan las frases "*Cena de Empresa*", "*Cena de Familia*", "*Cena de Compañeros*"...que sirve para indicar y exponer el carácter lúdico de la velada, también esta la "**Cena de Amigos**" o de manera más informal, "*Cena de Colegas*", con el mismo objetivo, animarse y divertirse.